# How to interact with "Messages" in applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to make an application automating the Messages app on Mac. One of the automations requires interactions with the conversation info button. I have tried to write a script to start playing around with it:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Messages"
        set infoButton to "Conversation Details"
        click toolbar item infoButton of toolbar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

However I receive the error: error `System Events got an error: Can’t get item \"Conversation Details\" of process \"Messages\"." number -1728 from item "Conversation Details" of process "Messages` Below I pasted a screenshot of using the Accessibility Inspector, which has the information surrounding the ui element I am trying to manipulate. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to click the **Conversation Details** *button* on the **Toolbar** of **Messages** in **macOS Big Sur**  with **AppleScript**, then the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will do it:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    if exists (buttons of ¬
        toolbars of ¬
        front window of ¬
        process "Messages" whose ¬
        description is "Conversation Details") ¬
        then click (buttons of ¬
        toolbars of ¬
        front window of ¬
        process "Messages" whose ¬
        description is "Conversation Details")
```

---

In short, it's:

```
button 2 of toolbar 1 of window 1 of application process "Messages"
```

However, I prefer to write it in an *error handling* method as in the full `tell` *statement* shown above this.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! Do you have any references you could link. I haven't used UI scripting with Applescript very much.

Comment: @S. Carr, RE: "Do you have any references you could link." --  Sorry, none in particular. I have learned much from experimenting and reading in general on the subject by utilizing Google searches.